# Raw Query on Array field Postgres Laravel

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I have table name `details` having `contains` field which stores array in postgres.

```
id    |   contents
 1    |   ["1", "2", "5"]
 2    |   ["4", "2", "10"]
 3    |   ["3", "5"]
```

If I query `5` it should return 2 records i.e. id `1` and `3`

I actually want to implement in laravel.

```
Details::whereRaw("contents ->> $id")->get(); // this doesn't work :p
```

How to raw query ?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Mysql (with JSON field) you would have used `JSON_CONTAINS()` or rather `JSON_SEARCH()` but because you are using postgresql then Perhaps you can find a solution from [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html). The one that looks quite close to an answer is this:

```
"SELECT * FROM details WHERE 5 = ANY (contents)"; //5 is the one of values in the array
```

There are also other ways such as using `ALL()`, `WHERE IN` etc. Unfortunately I have never used posgres with Laravel so I cannot really say how to construct the query, but perhaps simply doing the following would suffice:

```
Details::whereRaw("5 ANY (contents)")->get();
```

> PS: This answer is open for update if you got this working.

Comment: I got this error `SQLSTATE[42809]: Wrong object type: 7 ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side` I've defined `json`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `@>` ("contains") operator:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

`Details::whereRaw("contents ARRAY[?]::int[]', $id)`

`@>` is indexable if you use a GIN index https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html